# React Native: npx @rnx-kit/dep-check --set-version [major.minor] returns empty. Should I do anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dependency-management

I'm using the [React Native upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.4&to=0.64.0) to upgrade from 0.63.4 to 0.64.0.

The first thing it says is `You can use the following command to kick off the upgrade: npx @rnx-kit/dep-check --set-version [major.minor]`. I ran `npx @rnx-kit/dep-check --set-version 0.64` and it returned nothing.

Does this mean there are no incompatibilities and I'm good?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, if there are any outdated dependencies(critical) in the project it usually returns with a warn saying that the dependencies need to be updated .

Comment: If you have to comment , then use comment section

Comment: I didn't want to comment